# bring git repo up to a certain revision

Tags: git

I have a git repo, and a revision code I want it to get my local clone to. How can I bring it up to a specific revision and get rid of any changes I've made?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout the branch you want to mess with. Find the revision that you want in the log, then do:

```
$ git reset --hard abcd93
```

With *abcd93* being whatever version you found in the log. Note though, that this will change the branch pointer.

It is usually best to spawn off a new branch, so consider

```
$ git checkout abcd93 -b new_branch_name
```