# Git: update a repository to certain revision

Tags: git

Say I have a repository that has a revision number A. And I would like to update it to revision B, while the latest revision is C. (revision A is earlier than B, and B is earlier than C). I'm new to git so I did some research, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889984/bring-git-repo-up-to-a-certain-revision), which inspires me a solution:

```
git pull # update from A to the latest revision C
git reset --hard B
```

That does work. But since I can't `git reset --hard B` from A directly, the precedent update to latest is still too heavy, I wonder there might be some one-line command to match my need. Any hints please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no "updating a repository to a certain version". You repository has all the versions, that's what `git fetch` / `git pull` does.

If you want put a specific revision of the repo in your current working tree locally, there are several ways you could do that. The closest to your questions is:

update your local repository:

```
git fetch origin
```

create a new branch (from whatever branch you are currently on, we will reset hard later so it doesn't matter):

```
git branch yourbranchname
git checkout yourbranchname
```

The above 2 operations can be abbreviated into one (the current HEAD is assumed as source of the branch):

```
git checkout -b yourbranchname
```

then place the pointer of that branch to the commit you need (`B`):

```
git reset --hard sha1-of-B
```

git reset --hard will always work, it doesn't depend on your branch's history, the only condition for it to work is that commit B is in you local object base (i.e. B must exist and must have been fetched from a remote repo is it is not your work).

As @Hasturkun points out, you can also branch directly from any arbitrary hash with an extra argument:

```
git checkout -b yourbranchname SHA-1
```

Comment: You don't really need to reset the branch, as you can simply create it  with the start point being where you want it, ie. `git branch newbranch SHA1-of-B`, or `git checkout -b newbranch SHA1-of-B`

Comment: @Sébastien Thanks for introducing me some basic concepts.

Comment: @Hasturkun yes, I didn't want to enumerate all possible ways and thought this one might be easiest to understand given that the OP asked specifically about `reset --hard`. I can adapt the answer with your input. Thanks

Comment: I find this answer somewhat misleading: A `git reset` is neither what the OP needs to use, nor what he should use. The correct way to do this is a combination of `git checkout` and `git branch`. **Possibly destructive commands like `git reset hard` should not be recommended without necessity.**

Comment: This is so a difficult process, just to go to a revision. For Mercurial it's just hg update -r REV. And you don't lose any commits on top.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is entirely wrong. You are modifying something that you don't want to modify: Your current branch (presumably `master`).

A simple, linear git repository is a chain of commits like this

```
*---A---*---*---B---*---*---C
    ^                       ^
    |                       |
  master              origin/master
    ^
    |
   HEAD
```

That is the state of your repository after you have called `git fetch`. Note that the entire history with all its intermediate steps is right there on your local hard drive. It's just that you only have the state at commit `A` checked out (`HEAD` points to `master` which points to `A`), so the files that you see belong to that state.

Now, if you just want to look at the state that was committed as `B`, you can just check out that commit with `git checkout B`. This updates the files that you see to the state of `B`, and points `HEAD` at that commit:

```
*---A---*---*---B---*---*---C
    ^           ^           ^
    |           |           |
  master       HEAD   origin/master
```

`HEAD` always references the commit/branch that `git` thinks you are on, and to which it will compare your work directory when you call `git status`.

The simple `git checkout B` is sufficient, if you just want to look at that commit. If you actually want to make changes that you commit and want to preserve, you should introduce a new branch to record those changes. This is achieved by a simple `git checkout -b newBranch` after the `git checkout B`. This will give you the state

```
*---A---*---*---B---*---*---C
    ^           ^           ^
    |           |           |
  master    newBranch origin/master
                ^
                |
               HEAD
```

This just gives a name to commit `B` other than its hash value. After some more commits, your state would look like this:

```
*---A---*---*---B---*---*---C
    ^           |           ^
    |           |           |
  master         \    origin/master
                   \
                    *---*---D
                            ^
                            |
                        newBranch
                            ^
                            |
                           HEAD
```

The point is, that, after checking out some other branch/commit with `git checkout ...`, you can always easily return to commit `D` by calling `git checkout newBranch`, and the permanent reference stops `git` from garbage collecting commit `D`.

---

Now, why is using `git reset --hard` bad? First of all, it clobbers all your local changes that you have not committed yet without further notice. Second, it may loose you history if you are not careful with it.

Consider, for example, the case that you have made some changes after you last pushed to your upstream repository, and want to take a look at some historic commit `B`. (Somewhat the opposite of the case in your question.) The history looks like this:

```
  *---A---*---*---B---*---*---C
      ^                       ^
      |                       |
origin/master               master
                              ^
                              |
                             HEAD
```

With `git reset --hard B`, you get this state:

```
  *---A---*---*---B-(-*---*---C )
      ^           ^
      |           |
origin/master   master
                  ^
                  |
                 HEAD
```

The commits in parentheses are not referenced directly or indirectly by any branch anymore, and may be garbage collected any time. `git` may not be very aggressive with garbage collecting, **but if it does garbage collect while you are in this state, there is no way for you to get commit `C` back, it will be lost forever**. You don't want this to happen, so it's not a good idea to get into the habit of using `git reset --hard` lightly.

Had you used `git checkout` instead, the branch `master` would still be pointing at `C`, and you would still be able to get back to it with a simple `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `git checkout` for this. Just do:

git checkout B

and you'll have that revision.

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error using `git checkout`: `reference is not a tree`.

Comment: I thinks Hasturkun comment in Sébastien Dawans' answer will fix that problem for you.

Comment: Indeed, the help gives you: git checkout [OPTIONS] <branch>
It expects a branch, not a commit!

Comment: Nice and brief answer As it's supposed to be